# Can clouds quench thirst?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, everyday-life

Suppose you are standing on a mountain surrounded by clouds. You open your mouth and try to swallow the clouds (it's crazy, but still).

1. Can the droplets of water in the form of vapor actually be counted as 'drinking water'(or swallowing, same thing) ?
2. Will the clouds enter the body? And what happens when you breathe the clouds?
3. Or suppose you lower the temperature of the clouds(if you can), will it change to water?

Comment: I don't think that's a physics question, you should probably ask some biologists that.

Comment: Thought I'd get that answer.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I'd argue that 1 is purely a semantics question, 2a is unclear, 2b is probably for biologists & not physicists, 3 is on-topic here because it's atmospheric physics.

Comment: Are you asking about catching cloud water, such as done here: www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFydXBsgH6M ?

Answer (score 1):

First, water vapor is colorless, which means you cannot see water vapor directly. Clouds (or fog) is condensed water on dust particles.

> 1. Can the droplets of water in the form of vapor actually be counted as 'drinking water'(or swallowing, same thing) ?

If you can collect enough, yes.

> 2.Will the clouds enter the body? And what happens when you breathe the clouds?

The water sticks to the moisture already in the mouth and lungs.

> 3.Or suppose you lower the temperature of the clouds(if you can), will it change to water?

It already is water. If you lower the temperature enough, it will freeze.

Answer (score 1):

As a trekker and traveller who have been wandering in mountains a lot I say:

Clouds can't quench thirst. They are too sparse.

When you breathe clouds... nothing special happens.

Yes, cloud would change into water if it would be cooled. That's why one's glasses get "fogged" when you walk into crowded (therefore humid) room from a cold place. Water vapour turns into droplets when it touches cold glasses. It's called "condensation".